# Methods in visitor are not being called

Tags: java, antlr4

I'm experimenting with the visitor pattern. I've followed the examples in the book "The Definitive Antlr4 Reference" and I'm now trying things by myself.

The idea was to simply parse an XML file. I used a listener with success but I'm being stuck with the visitor. None of the methods are being called.

I use IntelliJ with the Antlr plug-in.

Here are the steps I followed :

- Test the grammar with the plug-in to validate it
- Generate a Listener and a Visitor
- Get some fun with the listener
- Failed with the visitor

To debug my visitor I used the following steps :

- Put a breakpoint in my class, but none of them are called in debug
- Put a breakpoint in the base class, the same result
- Trying with grammar from the book (chapter 4, 4.2 "Building a Calculator Using a Visitor") which gave me the expected result

Here is the grammar :

```
    grammar ClassLoaderXML ;

    root : 'Hello World' ;//node WS?;
    node : startTag WS* content+ endTag WS*;

    startTag : '<' identifiant (WS? attribut)* '>' ;
    endTag : '</' identifiant '>' ;

    attribut : identifiant WS? '=' WS? '\'' WORD (WS WORD)* '\'';
    identifiant : WORD ('-' WORD)*;

    content: WORD (WS? WORD)*  # string
            | node              # childNode
            ;

    WORD : [a-zA-Z]+ ;
    COMMENT : '<!--' .*? '-->' -> skip;
    WS  :  [ \t\n\r]+ ;
```

Here is my visitor class :

```
public class ClassLoaderVisitor extends ClassLoaderXMLBaseVisitor<String> {

@Override
public String visitRoot(ClassLoaderXMLParser.RootContext ctx){
    System.out.println("Hello world!");
    return visitChildren(ctx);
}

@Override
public String visitNode(ClassLoaderXMLParser.NodeContext ctx){
    System.out.println(ctx.getText());
    visitChildren(ctx.startTag());
    return ctx.getText();
}

@Override
public String visitIdentifiant(ClassLoaderXMLParser.IdentifiantContext ctx){
    visitChildren(ctx);
    return ctx.getText();
}
}
```

And here is my method in my main class :

```
    private static void LoadFile(String inputFile) throws IOException {
        CharStream input = CharStreams.fromFileName(inputFile);
        ClassLoaderXMLLexer lexer = new ClassLoaderXMLLexer(input);
        CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
        ClassLoaderXMLParser parser = new ClassLoaderXMLParser(tokens);
        ParseTree tree = parser.node();

        ClassLoaderXMLBaseVisitor visitor = new ClassLoaderXMLBaseVisitor();
        visitor.visit(tree);
}
```

**EDIT**
It was the wrong class instanciated in the last code snippet :

```
    ClassLoaderXMLBaseVisitor visitor = new ClassLoaderXMLBaseVisitor();
    visitor.visit(tree);
```

Should have been

```
    ClassLoaderVisitor visitor = new ClassLoaderVisitor();
    visitor.visit(tree);
```

Thank you @Carlos Heuberger

Comment: maybe I haven't seen it, but where is the instance of `ClassLoaderVisitor` being created? shouldn't it be `... visitor = new ClassLoaderVisitor()`

Comment: Holy Hell indeed! Such a rookie mistake!
Thank you a lot @CarlosHeuberger